# Java: Over use of 'static'

Tags: java, static

How do you use a variable outside any methods without the static key word? People say it shouldn't be done this way, Is there a better way?

Here is some code:

```
public class Main{

private static int a = 0;
private static int b = 1;       //<--- How to use these without the 'static' type?

public static void main(String[] args){ //Which will work here,

    Okay();

}

public static void Okay(){ //And here?
    if(a <= b){
        System.out.println("Alright");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Okay Then");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by removing all the uses of `static` (except for `public static void main`, you need that one)

In `public static void main`, create an instance of `Main` and call it's `Okay` method...

```
Main main = new Main();
main.Okay();
```

For example

```
public class Main {

    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) { //Which will work here,

        Main main = new Main();
        main.Okay();

    }

    public Main() {

    }

    public void Okay() { //And here?
        if (a <= b) {
            System.out.println("Alright");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Okay Then");
        }
    }

}
```

While this might seem trivial, if you have a class which was modifying the values in a number of different ways, then using instance classes like this will make a lot more sense, as you could create as many instances as you wanted and they would maintain their own versions of the values themselves, allowing you to manipulate different instances in different ways without effecting the others

You may also want to have a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 0):

By convention, Java method names start with a lower case letter. And you can pass the variables to the method,

```
public static void okay(int a, int b)
```

Or you can construct an User Defined Type (a custom object) and invoke a method there. Something like,

```
class OkayClass {
   int a;
   int b;
   // ... getters ... setters ...
   public OkayClass(int a, int b) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
   }
   public void okay() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

And then

```
OkayClass oc = new OkayClass(1, 2);
oc.okay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most common use cases for creating `static` methods are common utility methods. You'll see them all over the java standard library. See `Integer#parseInt()` , `String#valueOf()`, almost all the methods in `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.Collections`. `static` variable and methods are associated with class instead of individual instances of that class. Since `static` can't access non-static variables, they can never change the state of an instance. So as mentioned by [Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch), you can pass variables to the method.

That being said, many times you'll need to share `class'` state between all the instances or let users modify that state. In that case static variables with static methods are valid. For example you may not want a `HashMap` of zip code of all the cities, so you mark that `Map` `static`.